# How to set a JVM TimeZone Properly

Tags: java, jvm, windows-server-2008, timezone, java-5

I am trying to run a Java program, but it is taking a default GMT timezone instead of an OS defined timezone. My JDK version is 1.5 and the OS is Windows Server Enterprise (2007)

Windows has a Central timezone specified, but when I run the following program, it gives me a GMT time.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class DateTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(now.getTimeZone());
        System.out.println(now.getTime());
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",
offset=0,
dstSavings=0,
useDaylight=false,
transitions=0,
lastRule=null]
Mon Mar 22 13:46:45 GMT 2010
```

Please note that I do not want to set the timezone from the application. I want that the timezone used by JVM should be the one specified in the OS. (I am not finding this issues with other servers that have version 1.4 of JDK and Microsoft Server 2003).

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hm, that is strange. Looks like a JVM/OS bug or some weird misconfiguration.

Comment: how are you invoking the `DateTest` class?

Comment: @matt b: I am compiling and calling DateTest from windows command prompt. But this is just a Test class. The original problem was with some ETL process for IBM cognos server.

Comment: just wanted to rule out launching it through any shell/batch scripts which might be passing along a `-Duser.timezone` value

Answer (score 250, accepted):

You can pass the JVM this param

```
-Duser.timezone
```

For example

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Sofia
```

and this should do the trick. 
Setting the environment variable TZ also does the trick on Linux.

Comment: We had to use the JDK DST Timezone Update Tool - 1.3.25  (tzupdater) and then change the JVM parameter as you suggested and we finally got rid of the issue.

By the way, the timezone information is stored by Windows in some registry. The updater I used updated the registry values also.

Comment: I'm trying to startup my JVM using this parameter, but seems to have no change... If I want to start on UTC what shall I use as parameter!?

Comment: In my application I am changing some locations and getting timezones of that locations.Using the timezone I am processing further.But when the application starts for the first time,I am getting correct values. When i change the TimeZone and set the new timezone as default timezone, I am not getting the correct values.What is the issue? How to change the timezone exactly.I am changing the timezone using TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("my_time_zone"));

Comment: A list of the timezones for TZ is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones. Using the timezone name is better than the offset because it will handle daylight savings.

Answer (score 80):

You can also set the default time zone in your code by using following code.

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

To Yours

```
 TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Sofia"));
```

Comment: "Please note that I do not want to set the timezone from the application."

Answer (score 25):

The accepted answer above:

```
-Duser.timezone="Europe/Sofia"
```

Didn't work for me exactly. I only was able to successfully change my timezone when I didn't have quotes around the parameters:

```
-Duser.timezone=Europe/Sofia
```

Comment: I agree. I have edited the original answer to remove the quotes.

Comment: This depends on the used shell.

Answer (score 13):

On windows 7 and for JDK6, I had to add `-Duser.timezone="Europe/Sofia"` to the [JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions) system variable located under "My computer=>Properties=>Advanced System Settings=>Environment Variables".

If you already have some other property set for `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` just append a space and then insert your property string.

Answer (score 8):

Two options that I don’t think were covered in the other answers:

### Avoid the need

Whatever you do to set the JVM default time zone, it is very hard to make sure that no one else sets it differently. It can be set at any time without notice from another part of your program or from another program running in the same JVM. So in your time operations be explicit about which time zone you want, and you will always know what you get independently of the JVM setting. Example:

```
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Dushanbe")));
```

Example output:

> 2018-10-11T14:59:16.742020+05:00[Asia/Dushanbe]

### System.setProperty

For many purposes the following will not be the preferred way, and it can certainly be misused. For “throw away” programs I sometimes find it practical. You can also set a system property from within Java:

```
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", "Australia/Tasmania");
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now());
```

This just printed:

> 2018-10-11T21:03:12.218959+11:00[Australia/Tasmania]

If you want validation of the string you are passing, use:

```
        System.setProperty("user.timezone", ZoneId.of("Australia/Tasmania").getId());
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [Maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html):

```
mvn -Dexec.args="-Duser.timezone=Europe/Sofia ....."
```

Comment: `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Duser.timezone=UTC"` for Spring Boot v1.

Answer (score 2):

Setting environment variable `TZ` should also works

ex: `export TZ=Asia/Shanghai`

Comment: IMO the best option if you need to propagate this setting to subprocesses. A good example of it is to set this variable when starting Eclipse and then you have it in all JVMs started by Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

In win7, if you want to set the correct timezone as a parameter in JRE, you have to edit the file `deployment.properties` stored in path `c:\users\%username%\appdata\locallow\sun\java\deployment` adding the string `deployment.javaws.jre.1.args=-Duser.timezone\=`**my_time_zone**

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work (jvm executed from within intellij)