# Date vs Calendar vs Joda Time in DTO - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, date, calendar

I've learn to map usually the date fields in a DB to a `java.util.Date` field in a Java Bean. However, is this approach still useful? I know that `Date` are still in java mainly for backwards compatibility, and that Joda time tends to perform better than `java.util.Calendar`, but I'm not sure how well it goes with Hibernate.

So, my questions are the following:

- **In hibernate, which are the recomended data type for a Date field in a DB?**
  Date, Calendar, Joda Time, or any other?
- **It is still true when I don't care about the TimeZone or the Time portion?** For example, when I only want to store the date
- **What about pure Java beans?** Can I still implement the recommendations that are true for Hibernate mappings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you only want to store the date, then the appropriate Java class is `java.time.LocalDate`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715566) for how to get Hibernate to use that class.