# How to set default parameters to jvm?

Tags: java, windows, set, parameter-passing, jvm-arguments

I'd like to know how I can pass parameters to JVM before it is started. For example,

I think I need to modify JVM timezone parameter.

I use eclipse with windows 7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Eclipse go to

```
Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments
```

and set required JMV argument, eg

```
-Duser.timezone=PST
```

you can get all timezone IDs available in JVM by running this test

```
for(String id : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

output

```
Etc/GMT+12
Etc/GMT+11
Pacific/Midway
Pacific/Niue
Pacific/Pago_Pago
Pacific/Samoa
....
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. And another problem is that when I run this code:
`System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault());` output is
  sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Caracas",offset=-16200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=5,lastRule=null]  

How to change this another way?

Comment: Use one of the TimeZone methods eg TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()

Answer (score 4):

JVM parameters are specified in command line with `-D`

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar myApp.jar
```

In your case use `-Duser.timezone`

[How to set a JVM TimeZone Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly)

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @bmargulies, what is the difference? Post your answer.

Comment: Rereading his tortured syntax I'm no longer sure that there's a problem with your answer.

Comment: @bmargulies, yes, his question is not clear. The current two answers are supplemental to each other with current question formulation.

Comment: so what if I have no eclipse and no command line - is there a default configuration file? maybe some kind of default property file but where?