# On Windows7 Machine java.util.Date is in GMT, but Windows Clock App shows correct local time

Tags: java, windows-7, timezone

I have a Java application that shows various dates, all in the local time zone. It has always worked correctly in testing, on Windows 7. Now it has been moved to production to a Windows 7 machine in which the Clock shows the correct local time but all interactions with java.util.Date, java.util.TimeZone, etc. Tell me that Java thinks its local time zone is GMT.

What is even weirder is that, based on some information read elsewhere, I compared the registry settings for the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation key on a machine that did and a machine that did not exhibit the problem and found them to be identical?

What could cause this to occur? I have never seen anything like it. Is there some Windows 7 or Java setting for this that I don't know about?

Comment: Java uses CLDR mappings to determine the correct IANA zone to use from the local Windows zone.  See [the time zone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more info.  I'm not sure if perhaps these need to be updated in java?  Perhaps the Java runtime keeps its own value for the local time zone.  Not sure exactly.  I will research and answer better if nobody else gets to it first.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  I am trying to get to the bottom of the issue.  I'd rather not go the system property route of specifying the Time Zone, but I can't find any alternative.  There's nothing fancy going on here.  These computers are all in the Eastern timezone.  As I said above, the TimezoneInformation registry keys identical on machines that do and don't exhibit the problem.  What the heck is Java doing and does anyone know what other registry keys may get in the way of its getting this right?

Comment: Okay we've solved this.  Matt, you were right that it was a bad version of Java.  We are forced by corporate policy, since we need to include a nonstandard dll to run a "private" version of java and not the standard one.  This was installed in a wrapper that was supposed to contain the standard version of java plus our dll.  But a look with Winmerge at the directory structure told us that many files were missing including a bunch of timezone files.  But the rest of the package was intact.  Not sure how it happened but it explains the bizarre symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this computer has explicitly set the `user.timezone` parameter in the Java control panel or some other place on application startup?  [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly)

One other thing you can try (according to a user in the comments of [this article](http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2010/04/15/java-and-incorrect-timezone-on-windows-xp/)) is:

- Stop your application and any other Java apps.
- Change the time zone in Windows to something else (click apply).
- Change it back to the correct time zone.
- Relaunch your application.

Not sure if this is still applicable, since that article was about Windows XP, but this will certainly recreate all of the necessary timezone keys in the registry - just in case one of them is not set properly.

Also, make sure that machine has an updated version of Java.

Other than that, I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: Well, it is not the most up-to-date version of Java(1.6.0_26), but I don't think that should matter with a location in Miami, FL.

Comment: You are probably correct in that regard.  Try cycling the time zone and see if that helps.  Maybe something is haywire on that machine's registry settings and its too subtle to notice visually.