# retrieving date field from oracle with jpa decreased by a day

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, jpa

When I retrieve a table from database using JPA, Date fields are decreased by a day. ex :

in database I have 08/12/2013, the result in my Date object is 07/12/2013
I think this is because days of Java Date Class (java.util.Date) starts from 0 to 30.

Here is my field as declared in my entity bean:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="PROG_DATE_DEMANDE")
private Date progDateDemande;
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: How are you retrieving the day from progDateDemande?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `@Temporal` annotation?

Comment: Have you checked the time zones? There are many: Application server system TZ, TZ configured in Java of application server, database server system TZ and, maybe, TZ configured for the Oracle database.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos How to configure Application server system TZ ?

Comment: The location of the settings will vary with the application server. Which one are you using? In any case, in order to set the JVM timezone, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly). You must find the configuration file of the your application server that contains this property.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I'm using Glassfish v3.1

Comment: I set -Duser.timezone to "Europe/Paris" but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Make sure the server understands it. Have a JSP in your application print the result of the expression `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault()`. But note it may be due to the DB server timezone; or it may be another reason altogether.

Comment: Days in the Java Data Class do not start with 0, they start with 1. You confuse that with months, which indeed go from 0 to 11. I agree that this is most likely a timezone issue. Working with Oracle's DATE datatype and Java causes all kinds of funny effects.