# JVM Timezone is off by one hour

Tags: java, datetime, jvm, hour

Using Java 6 update 30 on a Windows XP machine. Updating Java or Windows is not an option.

I need a way to change the internal Java clock back one hour to match the system time. The machine is in Russia and Windows system time is correct, but the Java time is off by one hour, probably due to DST.

I have tried [changing JVM parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly) as well as modifying the deployment.properties file (to change the timezone), adding a variable to the environment/system variables path also did not work, and attempted the [timezone updater tool](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8054458) provided by Oracle. The first three do not change any parameters and the updater tool crashes, and says "Cannot find JRE/JDK files".

Is there any other way to permanently/properly change the time that Java is using.

example: 
Current Time : 7:20:17 PM TimeZone : sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo [id="Europe/Moscow",  offset=14400000, dstSavings=0, useDaylight=false, transitions=78, LastRule=null]

Required Time : 6:20:17 PM TimeZone : sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo [id="Europe/Moscow",  offset=14400000, dstSavings=0, useDaylight=false, transitions=78, LastRule=null]

Comment: I don't see any differences in the `TimeZone` object in your "current" and "required" examples. If the problem is in the time zone, there should be some difference there.

Comment: You are right that you need to update your timezone files as the Russian times changed last year.  So you need to figure out what is wrong with your usage of the tzupdater.  How exactly did you run it and what was the result?

Comment: When I ran the tzupdater tool the only output I got was that the JRE/JDK files could not be found.

Comment: http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzcode2014f.tar.gz The tool appears to only work with linux machines since it must use make.

Comment: Java uses tzdata but does not use tzcode.  It uses its own format for timezone information, hence the need for a tool such as tzupdater.

Comment: That's not a tool. That's just the IANA raw repository. It seems that [Oracle is distributing the tz updater only for the latest version of Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html#installation). Only their support customers can get access to the tz updater for older versions.

Comment: I have the tzupdater for my application 'Russia' that is the recommended tz updater but I get an error that says ' JRE/JDK files could not be found' in both interactive and non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your first two options - upgrade the JVM and use tzupdater - are not possible, you will have to use a workaround.  You can set the default timezone for the JVM using the `user.timezone` property.  You will need to set the timezone to a zone one hour away from the actual timezone to compensate for the 2014 changes.

Russian timezones available are

```
Europe/Kaliningrad
Europe/Moscow
Europe/Samara
Europe/Volgograd
Asia/Yekaterinburg
Asia/Novokuznetsk
Asia/Novosibirsk
Asia/Omsk
Asia/Krasnoyarsk
Asia/Irkutsk
Asia/Yakutsk
Asia/Sakhalin
Asia/Vladivostok
Asia/Anadyr
Asia/Kamchatka
Asia/Magadan
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem arose when attempting to get the current time from Glassfish Java Server and recieving an incorrect time stamp. In order to change the time zone it was necessary to find the domain.xml file and add a new time zone.

1. Open file domain.xml
2. Find other < jvm-options> tags
3. add  < jvm-options>-Duser.timezone="Europe/Berlin"< /jvm-options> (or another time zone)
4. restart Glassfish and hopefully it will change.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Moscow" )
)
```

## The Times They Are A-Changin'

Java 6 Update 30 shipped with Olson time zone data version 2011l, according to the [Update Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u30-relnotes-1394870.html). FYI, the Olson database is now known as the [‘tz database’](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) or ‘tzdata’.

Russia has experienced multiple changes to its time zones definitions since then. This makes puts your Java installation out-of-date. So you must either update the time zone database or use an alternative.

You said you tried but failed to update the time zone data.

## ThreeTen-Backport project

An alternative would be the back-port of much of the technology from the java.time classes that now supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`. Those old classes are now legacy and should be avoided. The back-port is found in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, and carries its own copy of `tzdb`. You can add this library to your project, and replace it as needed with future updates to the tzdata. See the [documentation to update tzdb](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/update-tzdb.html). By the way, the "ThreeTen" refers to [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

So for the purpose of your Java code, you do not care if the host operating system’s own time zone data is out-of-date, as we are not using that. Ditto for the JVM’s own time zone data, we are not using that. By using only the ThreeTen-Backport classes, we use the time zone data shipped as part of that library. And we can easily keep that time zone data fresh.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

> instant.toString(): 2017-01-16T07:43:24.130Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object representing the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) of a particular region.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Moscow" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2017-01-16T10:43:24.130+03:00[Europe/Moscow]

As a shortcut, you may skip dealing with the `Instant`, and call `ZonedDateTime.now( z )`.

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/8Ozc9t).

### Specify time zone

> Question: … Is there any other way to permanently/properly change the time that Java is using

Always pass a specific `ZoneId` rather than omit any optional time zone argument. When omitted, you are implicitly relying on the JVM’s current default time zone. That default can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM. So I strongly recommend you ***always* specify your desired/expected time zone** explicitly.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).