# Format current date and time at UTC in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am implementing integration with external service which requires current date and time. The documentation of the service says that it accepts the datetime in ISO 8601 format, but that's only partially true – it doesn't support timezone offset.

When I try `${date:now:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ}` in Camel, I get `2017-08-16T21:45:10+0200`, which is not acceptable by the service.

Is there a way to make Camel date format output current date in UTC? I would like to get `2017-08-16T19:45:10Z` instead of `2017-08-16T21:45:10+0200`.

I would like to avoid writing separate bean for that, so I prefer solution implemented purely in XML DSL.

Comment: The only way I see is to remove the timezone from the [format string](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and then [set the VM's default timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly) to `UTC`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've managed to come up with a solution using Groovy expression:

```
<groovy>
  java.time.ZonedDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)
      .format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"))
</groovy>
```

Answer (score 6):

Camel [Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) language has `date-with-timezone` variable that can be used to query time of different time zones like:

```
${date-with-timezone:now:CET:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss}
${date-with-timezone:now:UTC:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss}
${date-with-timezone:now:EST:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss}
```

That would become:

```
2022-03-22T16:08:43 // CET is UTC+1
2022-03-22T15:08:43 // UTC
2022-03-22T10:08:43 // EST is UTC-5
```

The last parameter is [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern that you can use to get whatever time zone designator you would like to have. E.g.

```
${date-with-timezone:now:UTC:yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX}
```

Gives you:

```
2022-03-22T15:08:43Z
```