# Setting time zone of hsqldb by using url

Tags: hsqldb, liquibase

is there any way to set up database timezone using url properties? Currently it seems to be UTC+2hours but in my test its just UTC, so tests fail because of time difference (Im inserting 00:00 but during verification hour fetched from db is 02:00).
 I know it can be done by `SET TIME ZONE` but I dont have any script initializing db in tests, its just liquibase file which is exactly same as for production code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JVM time zone, as answered here: [How to set a JVM TimeZone Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly)

Now if you need to test against a database that is running in UTC but your program is not running in UTC, you need to start an HSQLDB server in a separate process running in UTC.