# Any difference between java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone() vs java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()?

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, java-time

Is there any difference in between the two, given that both `java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone()` and `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()` return the same output.

For instance this code

```
import java.time.Clock;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone() : " 
        + Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone());
    System.out.println("TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId() : " 
        + TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId());
  }

}
```

returns this output

```
Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone() : Europe/Paris
TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId() : Europe/Paris
```

Comment: The main difference is that `TimeZone` is outdated (though not yet officially deprecated) while `Clock` is modern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both returns the JVM's default timezone (in the end, `Clock` calls `TimeZone.getDefault()`, as explained in [@Kiskae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45794087/7605325)), but it's not guaranteed that all calls will **always** return the same value **everytime**.

That's because the default timezone can be changed:

- the system where the JVM is running can change its configuration. In Windows machines, for example, this [information is read from the registry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/time-zone001.html#CBBIEBDG), while in Linux it gets from `/etc/localtime` (usually a link to a specific file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`) or another similar folder (it can vary in each version/distribution), or by setting the `TZ` environment variable. If this system configuration changes it and the JVM is restarted, suddenly your code starts returning different values
- the JVM [can be configured to use a different timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2493805/7605325), regardless of OS's config. One example is when the maintanance/infrastructure team changes this configuration (on purpose or by accident, and usually without telling the developers...) and then your code doesn't return the same values anymore (and everything that depends on the timezone will suddenly break)
- your application (or another application running the same JVM) calls [`TimeZone.setDefault()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)). This will affect all the applications running in the same JVM, **at runtime**, so if you run this code:

  ```
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
  System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault());

  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
  System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault());

  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault());
  ```

The output will be:

> Europe/London
>   America/New_York
>   UTC

Note how easily the default timezone is changed at runtime, and all subsequent calls to get it are affected. The same will happen if you call `Clock.systemDefaultZone().getZone()` or `TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()`, because both uses the default timezone.

As this changes the JVM's default timezone, all applications running in the same JVM will be affected by it. This might lead to unexpected errors that are hard to debug.

Although the methods that use the default timezone are convenient, you must check how your code depends on it and how it can be affected if the zone changes.

If you don't want to depend on the default, the ideal is to use a specific timezone, such as `ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris")`. Always prefer [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/New_York` or `Europe/Paris`).
Avoid using the short abbreviations (like `CET` or `CEST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code on grepcode, they end up executing the exact same methods, resulting in the same result. `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` calls `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, which returns `TimeZone.getDefault().toZoneId()`:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/time/ZoneId.java#ZoneId.systemDefault%28%29