# How can I return LocalDate.now() in milliseconds?

Tags: java-8, timestamp, java-time, localdate

I create date now:

```
ZoneId gmt = ZoneId.of("GMT");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDate localDateNow = localDateTime.toLocalDate();
```

Then I want return this date in milliseconds:

```
localDateNow.atStartOfDay(gmt) - 22.08.2017
localDateNow.atStartOfDay(gmt).toEpochSecond(); - 1503360000 (18.01.70)
```

How can I return `LocalDate.now()` in milliseconds?

Comment: How can a date have milliseconds? Milliseconds is part of the timestamp not of the date

Comment: @Jens localDateTime.atZone(gmt).toEpochSecond() return 1503403331 (18.01.70) to

Comment: What you are talking about `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`? You ask for LocalDate and give example for `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Instand aof calling toEpochSecond(), call toInstant().toEpochMilli()

Comment: @JB Nizet Thank you! exactly what is needed!

Answer (score 58):

Calling `toInstant().toEpochMilli()`, as suggested by [@JB Nizet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813379/how-can-i-return-localdate-now-in-milliseconds#comment78584532_45813379), is the right answer, but there's a little and tricky detail about using local dates that you must be aware of.

But before that, some other minor details:

- Instead of `ZoneId.of("GMT")` you can use the built-in constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`. They're equivalent, but there's no need to create extra redundant objects if the API already provides one that does exactly the same thing.
- Instead of calling `LocalDateTime.now()` and then `.toLocalDate()`, you can call `LocalDate.now()` directly - they're equivalent.

---

Now the tricky details: when you call the `now()` method (for either `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate`), it uses the JVM's default timezone to get the values for the current date, and this value might be different depending on the timezone configured in the JVM.

In the JVM I'm using, the default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo`, and the local time here is **09:37 AM**. So `LocalDate.now()` returns `2017-08-22` (August **22<sup>th</sup>** 2017).

But if I change the default timezone to [`Pacific/Kiritimati`](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/kiribati/kiritimati), it returns `2017-08-23`. That's because in Kiritimati, right now is already August **23<sup>th</sup>** 2017 (and the local time there, at the moment I write this, is **02:37 AM**).

So, if I run this code when the default timezone is `Pacific/Kiritimati`:

```
LocalDate dtNow = LocalDate.now(); // 2017-08-23
System.out.println(dtNow.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

The output is:

> 1503446400000

Which is the equivalent of August **23<sup>th</sup>** 2017 at midnight in UTC.

If I run the same code when the default timezone is `America/Sao_Paulo`, the result will be:

> 1503360000000

Which is the equivalent of August **22<sup>th</sup>** 2017 at midnight in UTC.

Using `now()` makes your code depends on the JVM's default timezone. And this configuration [can be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), making your code return different results when such change occurs.

And you don't need such an extreme case (like someone misconfiguring the JVM to a "very-far" timezone). In my case, for example, in `America/Sao_Paulo` timezone, if I run the code at **11 PM**, `LocalDate` will return August **22<sup>th</sup>**, but the current date in UTC will already be August **23<sup>th</sup>**. That's because 11 PM in São Paulo is the same as 2 AM of the **next day** in UTC:

```
// August 22th 2017, at 11 PM in Sao Paulo
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 8, 22, 23, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(z); // 2017-08-22T23:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
System.out.println(z.toInstant()); // 2017-08-23T02:00:00Z (in UTC is already August 23th)
```

So using a `LocalDate.now()` is **not** a guarantee that I'll always have the **current date in UTC**.

---

If you want the **current date in UTC** (regardless of the JVM default timezone) and set the time to midnight, it's better to use a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
// current date in UTC, no matter what the JVM default timezone is 
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// set time to midnight and get the epochMilli
System.out.println(zdtNow.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

The output is:

> 1503360000000

Which is the equivalent of August **22<sup>th</sup>** 2017 at midnight in UTC.

Another alternative is to pass the timezone to `LocalDate.now`, so it can get the correct values for the current date on the specified zone:

```
// current date in UTC, no matter what the JVM default timezone is 
LocalDate dtNowUtc = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// set time to midnight and get the epochMilli
System.out.println(dtNow.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```