# Spring Boot parse form data to ZonedDateTime (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-time, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I have an entity which has `java.time.ZonedDateTime` property. I want to parse a string submitted from form in `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` format to `java.time.ZonedDateTime`.

I tried `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")`. But it works only `LocalDate` with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")` format.

I also created a `Converter` as below

```
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

    private final ZoneId zoneId;

    public ZonedDateTimeConverter(ZoneId zoneId) {
        this.zoneId = zoneId;
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
        LOG.info("Parsing string {} to ZonedDateTime: {}", source, ZonedDateTime.parse(source, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(source, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
    }
}
```

and overwriting webMvcConfiguration as below

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new ZonedDateTimeConverter(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is the right way to make it work.
Using Spring Boot 1.5.6. Thymeleaf 3.0.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DateTimeFormatter`'s pattern has only the date (`dd/MM/yyyy`) and time (`HH:mm`), but a `ZonedDateTime` also needs a timezone to be parsed directly.

As the input doesn't have it, one alternative is to first parse the input to a `java.time.LocalDateTime` and then convert it to a `ZoneDateTime`, using the `zoneId` that you already have:

```
public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
    // parse to LocalDateTime
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(source, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
    // convert to ZonedDateTime
    return dt.atZone(this.zoneId);
}
```

---

Another alternative is to set the timezone in the formatter, so you can parse directly to a `ZonedDateTime`. But in this case, I also suggest you a refactor: make the formatter a field of your converter class (instead of a `static` field), because it'll depend on the `ZoneId` you pass in the constructor.

```
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter;

    public ZonedDateTimeConverter(ZoneId zoneId) {
        // set the zone in the formatter
        this.formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm").withZone(zoneId);
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(String source) {
        // now the formatter has a zone set, so I can parse directly to ZonedDateTime
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(source, this.formatter);
    }
}
```

---

Just a note about using `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. This method gets the JVM's default timezone, but keep in mind that [it can be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to always specify which timezone you want to use.

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Berlin`). Then you create the timezone using `of` method, such as `ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata")`.

Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `IST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). Some of them **might** work (usually due to retro-compatibility reasons), but it's not guaranteed.

You can get a list of all available timezones (and choose the best for your case) with `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a configuration that will convert automatically ZonedDateTime fields from String as follows:

```
package com.example.config;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry;
import org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeFormatterRegistrar;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

/**
 * Configure the converters to use the ISO format for dates by default.
 */
@Configuration
public class DateTimeFormatConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(@NotNull FormatterRegistry registry) {
        DateTimeFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateTimeFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setUseIsoFormat(true);
        registrar.registerFormatters(registry);
    }
}
```