# Hours difference while considering the date

Tags: java, datetime, date-difference, date

I need to extract the date field from DB and store it in a VO. How can I compare the hours difference from two dates.

**For ex:**
Let's say `date1 = 01-SEP-17 10:00:00` and `date2 = 05-SEP-17 12:00:00`. I need to compare the two dates and perform some operations like:

```
if(hours>10){
//do something
}
if(hours<10){
//do something else
}
```

I'm just able to calculate the difference between the hours (date2-date1) as 2 but how to consider the date too while calculating the difference between the hours?

My present code:

```
Date dateA = someVO.getDate();  
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();  
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YY HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date1 = new Date(date); 
Date date2 = df.parse(dateA.toString());  
long date1Hours = date1.getHours();
long date2Hours = date2.getHours();  

long dateDiff = date1Hours-date2Hours;  
if(dateDiff>10){  
//something
}  
else if(dateDiff<10){  
//something else
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the pattern used in `SimpleDateFormat`, and also use a `java.util.Locale` to specify that the month name is in English (otherwise it uses the system default locale, and it's not guaranteed to always be English).

Then you get the correspondent millis value of each `Date`, calculate the difference between them and convert this to hours, using a `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date1 = df.parse("01-SEP-17 10:00:00");
Date date2 = df.parse("05-SEP-17 12:00:00");

// get the difference in hours
long dateDiff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
```

`dateDiff` will be `98`.

If you want to compare with the current date, just use `new Date()`.

---

## Daylight Saving Time issues

There's one problem with this approach. Although it doesn't make a difference for most part of the year, there can be differences due to [Daylight Saving Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/) changes.

By default, `SimpleDateFormat` uses the JVM default timezone. If between the 2 dates there's a Daylight Saving Time changeover (or just an offset change), the result might be different.

Example: in [`Africa/Windhoek` timezone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/namibia/windhoek), in September 3<sup>rd</sup> 2017, at 2 AM, clocks shifted 1 hour forward, from 2 AM to 3 AM (and the offset changed from `+01:00` to `+02:00`). This means that, at that day, all local times between 2 AM and 2:59 AM don't exist in this timezone (it's like they "skipped" this hour).

So, if the JVM default timezone is `Africa/Windhoek`, then the difference using the code above will be 97 hours (and not 98).

Even if your JVM default timezone is not `Africa/Windhoek`, this can still happen, depending on the timezone and the dates involved.
Not only that, but the default timezone [can be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325). It's always better to specify which timezone you're working with instead of just relying on the default.

You can't avoid DST effects (unless you use UTC), but at least you can choose which timezone you're going to use instead of relying on the system default (that can be changed without notice).

It's possible to set a timezone in the formatter, so all dates will be parsed taking this timezone into account. In the example below, I'm using `Europe/London`, but of course you can change to one that best suits your case:

```
// set Europe/London timezone in the SimpleDateFormat
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
```

Now all the parsed dates will be considered to be in London timezone (but remind that DST effects will still be considered - the advantage is that you know what timezone you're using and any changes in the JVM's default won't make your code suddenly start giving different and unexpected results).

Always use [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of all timezones using `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` - then you can choose the one that best suits your case.

If you don't want to consider DST effects, you can use `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")` - because [UTC is a standard without DST changes](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

The old classes (`Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`) have [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571265/why-is-the-java-date-api-java-util-date-calendar-such-a-mess) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api), and they're being replaced by the new APIs.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the **package names** (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

First you need to parse the inputs (using a `DateTimeFormatter`) and specify in what timezone they are. As the dates also have a timezone, I'm using a `ZonedDateTime`, which is the best choice for this case.

Then you can easily calculate the difference in hours using a `ChronoUnit`. In the example below, I'm also using London timezone as an example:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // case insensitive for month name in all caps
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    // date/time pattern
    .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss")
    // use English locale for month name
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH)
    // set a timezone
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
// parse the dates
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("01-SEP-17 10:00:00", fmt);
ZonedDateTime z2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("05-SEP-17 12:00:00", fmt);
// calculate the difference in hours
long diffHours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(z1, z2);
```

If you want to use UTC, just change the `ZoneId` to `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant. If you want to compare with the current date, just use:

```
// use the same ZoneId used in the formatter if you want to consider DST effects
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

---

## Conversions to/from Date

If you still need to work with `java.util.Date`, it's possible to convert from/to the new API. In Java 8 you can use native methods, and in Java <=7 the ThreeTen Backport has the `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class.

To convert a `Date` to the new classes:

```
Date date = // java.util.Date
// convert to zoneddatetime (java 8)
ZonedDateTime z = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
// convert to zoneddatetime (java 7 ThreeTen Backport)
ZonedDateTime z = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

To convert a `ZonedDateTime` back to a date:

```
// convert to zoneddatetime (java 8)
Date date = Date.from(z.toInstant());
// convert to zoneddatetime (java 7 ThreeTen Backport)
Date date = DateTimeUtils.toDate(z.toInstant());
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy enough to do using the new Java-Time API added in Java 8:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                        .parseCaseInsensitive()
                        .appendPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss")
                        .toFormatter(Locale.US);
LocalDateTime date1 = LocalDateTime.parse("01-SEP-17 10:00:00", fmt);
LocalDateTime date2 = LocalDateTime.parse("05-SEP-17 12:00:00", fmt);
long hours = ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(date1, date2);
System.out.println(hours);
```

*Output*

```
98
```

Answer (score 1):

You've essentially already got the times in milliseconds. You could always just compare the milliseconds directly instead.

```
long tenHoursInMillis = 36000000;
long dateVOMillis = someVO.getDate().getTime();
long dateSysMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(dateSysMillis - dateAMillis > tenHoursInMillis) {
    // do something
}
else if(dateSysMillis - dateAMillis < tenHoursInMillis) {
    // do something else
}
// do something when they're equal
```