# Why Calendar.SEPTEMBER is not working?

Tags: java, android, calendar, java.util.calendar

I want to see a month which contains whole days.

```
private void createRandomData(InMemoryCursor cursor) {
    List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
    today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    mStart = (Calendar) today.clone();
    mStart.add(Calendar.SEPTEMBER, -5);
    while (mStart.compareTo(today) <= 0) {
        data.add(createItem(mStart.getTimeInMillis()));
        mStart.add(Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 1);
    }
    cursor.addAll(data);
}
```

When I write Calendar.SEPTEMBER(or other months), I see red line on Calendar.SEPTEMBER which contains:

> Must be one of: Calendar.ERA, Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND, Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET, Calendar.DST_OFFSET less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   This inspection looks at Android API calls that have been annotated with various support annotations (such as RequiresPermission or UiThread) and flags any calls that are not using the API correctly as specified by the annotations.  Examples of errors flagged by this inspection:
>   Passing the wrong type of resource integer (such as R.string) to an API that expects a different type (such as R.dimen).
>   Forgetting to invoke the overridden method (via super) in methods that require it
>   Calling a method that requires a permission without having declared that permission in the manifest
>   Passing a resource color reference to a method which expects an RGB integer value.
>   ...and many more.  For more information, see the documentation at developer.android.com/tools/debugging/annotations.html

When I run it despite the red line, It shows complicated dates like: 
[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GPvh.png)

I use this library from GitHub:https://github.com/jruesga/timeline-chart-view 
Is problem related to library? or It is about Java calendar?

Comment: You have already been answered: `Must be one of: Calendar.ERA, Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DATE, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.HOUR, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE, Calendar.SECOND, Calendar.MILLISECOND, Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET, Calendar.DST_OFFSET`

Comment: Isn't possible see as I want?@ModularSynth

Comment: Do you see it listed in the available options?

Comment: I am asking why it must be like them

Comment: Ask it to the library author.

Comment: Does `mStart.add(Calendar.SEPTEMBER, ...)` really make sense? I mean, what should you get if you added September to today?

Comment: If it was an option, then you would have also liked something like `Calendar.MONDAY, ... Calendar.SUNDAY`. But well, these kind of enumerations simply don't make any sense in a Calendar object.

Comment: Even if I use other months or removing today.clone, it shows the same result. It doesn't matter as I said. Thanks for the effort, I will work on it.

Comment: Your job will be easier and your code much more natural to read if you use `LocalDate` from ThreeTenABP rather than the long outdated `Calendar` class. See [Hugo’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081075/5772882) and its helpful links.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [@Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46080104/7605325), you can't use `Calendar.SEPTEMBER` in the `add` method.

If you want to add or subtract a specified number of months, just use `Calendar.MONTH`. If you want to add/subtract days, you use `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` and so on.

The `Calendar` API might be confusing sometimes (most times, IMO), and has [lots of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265/7605325) and [design issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

In Android, there's a better alternative: you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. To make it work, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

As you're getting a `Calendar` in the default timezone, a good candidate for replacement is a `org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime` (it represents a date and time in a specific timezone). First I use the `now()` method (that takes the current date/time at the JVM default timezone). Then I use a `org.threeten.bp.LocalTime` to set the time to midnight.

I also use the `minusMonths` method to get a date 5 months before the current date, and inside the loop I use the `toInstant()` method, to get the millis value, and the `plusMonths` method to get the next month:

```
// get today at default timezone, at midnight
ZonedDateTime today = ZonedDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
// 5 months ago
ZonedDateTime start = today.minusMonths(5);
while (start.compareTo(today) <= 0) {
    data.add(createItem(start.toInstant().toEpochMilli()));
    start = start.plusMonths(1);
}
```

If you want to add/subtract minutes instead of months, for example, you can use the methods `minusMinutes` and `plusMinutes`. There are other methods for another units as well (such as hours, days, and so on), [check the javadoc](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/ZonedDateTime.html#method_summary) to see all the options.

---

The problem of using the default timezone is that it [can  be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using.

With `Calendar`, you can use `TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneName)`:

```
Calendar todayCal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"), Locale.getDefault());
```

And with ThreeTen Backport, you can use `ZoneId.of(zoneName)`:

```
ZonedDateTime today = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
```

In the example above, I used `Europe/London`, but you can change it to any timezone you want. The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` or `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an incompatible option. The first parameter of [`Calendar.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) is a Unit of Time (Day, Week, Hour etc) as defined by the possible options outlined in the error. `Calendar.SEPTEMBER` is not a unit of time, it is a convenience constant representing the [`MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH) of September that is typically used in the [`set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int)) method instead.

Assuming you're iterating through months, you'll need `Calendar.MONTH` instead.