# How to deserialize a Timestamp as-is using Jackson Annotation in Java?

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, utc

I have a field in my Java Bean like below where `@JsonFormat` is a jackson annotation:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
private Timestamp createdOn;
```

When I return the `Timestamp`, it is always getting converted to UTC time in my JSON response. Lets say on formatting my Timestamp , I get `2017-09-13 15:30` but my response is getting returned as `2017-09-13 10:00`.

I know this is because of Jackson annotation by default takes the System TimeZone and converts the Timestamp to UTC. (In my case the server belongs to `Asia/Calcutta` time zone and thus the offset is `+05:30` and the Jackson mapper subtracts 5 hrs and 30 minutes to convert the Timestamp to UTC)

Is there a way I return the Timestamp as-is, i.e, `2017-09-13 15:30` instead of `2017-09-13 10:00`?

Comment: If your timezone offset is 5:30, why is there only 5 hours between the times? Where did the 30 minutes go?

Comment: Fixed the typo!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made a test here, changing the JVM default timezone to `Asia/Calcutta` and creating a class with a `java.sql.Timestamp` field:

```
public class TestTimestamp {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private Timestamp createdOn;

    // getter and setter
}
```

In your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46162583/7605325) you told that JDK 8 is being used, so I tested in the same version (if you're using another version (JDK <= 7), check the *"Not Java 8"* section in the bottom). First I created a `Timestamp` that corresponds to **September 13<sup>th</sup> 2017, at 10 AM in UTC**:

```
TestTimestamp value = new TestTimestamp();
// timestamp corresponds to 2017-09-13T10:00:00 UTC
value.setCreatedOn(Timestamp.from(Instant.parse("2017-09-13T10:00:00Z")));
```

Then I serialized it with Jackson's `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String s = om.writeValueAsString(value);
```

The resulting `String` is:

> {"createdOn":"2017-09-13 10:00"}

Note that, in the generated JSON, the output is in UTC (10 AM). If I deserialize this JSON:

```
value = om.readValue(s, TestTimestamp.class);
System.out.println(value.getCreatedOn());
```

This will print:

> 2017-09-13 15:30:00.0

That's because the `Timestamp::toString()` method (which is implicity called in `System.out.println`) prints the timestamp in the JVM default timezone. In this case, the default is `Asia/Calcutta`, and **10 AM in UTC** is the same as **15:30 in Calcutta**, so the output above is produced.

As I explained in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46162732/7605325), a `Timestamp` object doesn't have any timezone information. It has just the number of nanoseconds since unix epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z` or *"January 1st 1970 at midnight in UTC"*).

Using the example above, if you see the value of `value.getCreatedOn().getTime()`, you'll see that it's `1505296800000` - that's the number of milliseconds since epoch (to get the nanoseconds precision, there's the method `getNanos()`).

This milliseconds value corresponds to 10 AM in UTC, 7 AM in São Paulo, 11 AM in London, 7 PM in Tokyo, 15:30 in Calcutta and so on. You don't convert the `Timestamp` between zones, because the millis value is the same everywhere in the world.

What you can change, though, is the **representation** of this value (the corresponding date/time in a specific timezone).

In Jackson, you can create custom serializers and deserializers (by extending `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer`), so you can have more control over how you format and parse the dates.

First I create a serializer that formats the `Timestamp` to the JVM default timezone:

```
public class TimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Timestamp value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // get the timestmap in the default timezone
        ZonedDateTime z = value.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        String str = fmt.format(z);

        gen.writeString(str);
    }
}
```

Then I create a deserializer that reads the date in the JVM default timezone and creates the `Timestamp`:

```
public class TimestampDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Timestamp> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    @Override
    public Timestamp deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // parse to a LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(jsonParser.getText(), fmt);
        // the date/time is in the default timezone
        return Timestamp.from(dt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}
```

I also change the field to use these custom classes:

```
// remove JsonFormat annotation
@JsonSerialize(using = TimestampSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = TimestampDeserializer.class)
private Timestamp createdOn;
```

Now, when using the same `Timestamp` above (that corresponds to `2017-09-13T10:00:00Z`). Serializing it produces:

> {"createdOn":"2017-09-13 15:30"}

Note that now the output corresponds to the local time in the JVM default timezone (15:30 in `Asia/Calcutta`).

When deserializing this JSON, I get back the same `Timestamp` (corresponding to 10 AM in UTC).

---

This code uses the JVM default timezone, but it [can  be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using.

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Calcutta` or `Europe/Berlin`), so you can create them using `ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta")`.
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `IST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

If you want to change the output to correspond to another timezone, just change `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to the zone you want. Just keep in mind that the same zone must be used to both serialize and deserialize, otherwise you'll get wrong results.

---

## Not Java 8?

If you're using Java <= 7, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes.

The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

There's also another difference: only in Java 8 the `Timestamp` class has the methods `toInstant()` and `from()`, so you'll need to use `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` class to make the conversions:

```
public class TimestampSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Timestamp> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Timestamp value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // get the timestmap in the default timezone
        ZonedDateTime z = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(value).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        String str = fmt.format(z);

        gen.writeString(str);
    }
}

public class TimestampDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Timestamp> {

    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    @Override
    public Timestamp deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // parse to a LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(jsonParser.getText(), fmt);
        // the date/time is in the default timezone
        return DateTimeUtils.toSqlTimestamp(dt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hugo. I extended the JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer classes and not only I got what I wanted but right now I have the full control over my Request/Response formatting. Well, the old school saying 'Do it yourself' never goes old actually....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`timeZone`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html#timezone()) to specify the timezone you want explicitly :

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", timezone="Asia/Calcutta")
private Timestamp createdOn;
```

Comment: This is not what I expected. Thanks though. Since I use Cloud Services, I have the liberty to change the location of my Server. Hence I can not afford to change the timezone in my Bean whenever I change the server location.

Comment: @PrasathGovind Did you try `timezone=JsonFormat.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE`?

Comment: Nope. I tried timezone=JsonFormat.DEFAULT_TIMEZONE, timezone="GMT" and timezone="UTC" nothing worked. All the annotations I tried, subtracted 5hrs 30mts from the Timestamp. I wanted to return as-is without subtraction.

Comment: @PrasathGovind Are you *sure* your servers time zone is `Asia/Calcutta`, and not `UTC`? I.e. what is the value of [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--)?

Comment: @Andreas : TimeZone.getDefault() returned Asia/Calcutta

Comment: @PrasathGovind Can you try thr same with the format specified in the link once. Though I would suspect the zone is getting changed some place or the other in code.

Comment: My experience has been that using the annotation, `timezone = "UTC"` will only work on `LocalDateTime`'s