# Receiving same ZonedDateTime for different time strings

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time, datetime-parsing

I'm using the below function to convert a microsecond format time string to `ZoneDateTime` so I can do comparisons later.

```
public static ZonedDateTime createTimeFromString(String inputTime) {
    ZonedDateTime time;
    try {

        System.out.printf("Input time %s%n", inputTime);
        DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(inputTime, formatter);
        time = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        System.out.printf("Formated time %s%n", time);
        return time;
    }
    catch (DateTimeParseException exc) {
        System.out.printf("%s is not parsable!%n", inputTime);
        throw exc;      // Rethrow the exception.
    }
}
```

However, whatever time string I pass into the function I get the same output.

eg:

```
Input time 20171025-10:58:24.062151
Formated time 2017-10-25T00:00+05:30[Asia/Colombo]

Input time 20171025-10:58:25.446862
Formated time 2017-10-25T00:00+05:30[Asia/Colombo]
```

I'm using Java 8.

Can you please clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `LocalDate.parse`, you're getting just the date part (day, month and year) and discarding the rest. A `LocalDate` doesn't have the time fields (hour, minute, seconds and fraction of second), so they are simply discarded and lost.

Then you call `atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())`, which sets the time to **midnight** at the JVM default timezone.

If you want to keep everything (date and time), parse it to a `LocalDateTime`, which is a class that contains all the date and time fields. Then you call the `atZone` method to convert it to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
String inputTime = "20171025-10:58:24.062151";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS");
// parse to a LocalDateTime (keeping all date and time fields)
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(inputTime, formatter);
// convert to ZonedDateTime
ZonedDateTime z = date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

---

**PS:** `ZoneId.systemDefault()` returns the JVM default timezone, but keep in mind that this [can be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132), so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using.

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Colombo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `IST` or `CET`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. Then you call the `ZoneId.of()` method with the zone name, like this:

```
// using specific timezone instead of JVM's default
ZonedDateTime z = date.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Colombo"));
```