# Java time ignores daylight saving rules

Tags: java, time, timezone, posix, dst

I am exporting `TZ` variable in POSIX format to set timezone on Linux. For instance:

```
export TZ="EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/02:00,M11.1.0/02:00"
```

Linux `date` command returns:

> Wed Mar 14 03:47 EDT 2018

Java `ZonedDateTime.now()` returns:

> 2018-03-14T02:47:36.808[GMT-05:00]

It seems that Java does not take into account DST rule. What can be wrong?

Comment: What is `ZoneId.systemDefault()` returning?

Comment: At a guess, your JVM doesn't attempt to parse anything after the first comma. For example `TZ="EST+5EDT,I'm a little teapot"` produces the same output as `TZ="EST+5EDT,M3.2.0/02:00,M11.1.0/02:00"`.

Comment: @JoeC ZoneId.systemDefault() returns GMT-05:00

Comment: @AndyTurner It seems like JVM bug, Do you have any ideas to go around it ?

Comment: "It seems like JVM bug" whether it is a bug depends upon whether the JVM is intended to support this timezone format  - I've looked, and can't find anything which says it should. You can write something which parses the string yourself, and then create an instance of [`SimpleTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html) (or just create a "fixed" instance, and set it as your default on startup).

Comment: But by all means file it as a bug with Oracle if you think it is; let them decide.

Comment: Looking [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/TimeZone.java#669), it looks as though Java only supports fixed-offset custom time zones if the time zone isn't one it recognizes.

Comment: Why do you want to define your own time zone rules? What’s wrong with America/New_York time zone?

Comment: Noting wrong but installed linux env has only one options to set timezone(exporting TZ variable in Posix format), so OS will not able to understand America/New_York format

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you, it looks like there are no ways to learn Java understand posix timezone without spike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what linux version you're using, but I've tested in Red Hat 4.4 and it accepts [IANA's names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones):

```
export TZ=America/New_York
date
```

And the output is:

> Qua Mar 14 08:37:25 EDT 2018

I've also checked some articles on web and all examples use names like "America/New_York", "Europe/London" and so on.

But anyway, if your linux version doesn't work with this, it's better to change your code to not use the JVM default timezone:

```
ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
```

Actually, I think it's better to use a specific timezone, because the default [can be changed at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185444), for **any** application running in the same JVM. Even if you have control over what the applications do, some infrastructure/environment maintainance can change that, either on purpose or by accident - it happened to me once, which made me start using explicit timezones names everywhere.

And always prefer IANA's names, in the format `Continent/Region`. Names like `EST+5EDT` are fixed, in the sense that they represent just an offset (in this case, GMT-05:00), without any Daylight Saving rules. Only names like `America/New_York` contains DST rules.