# When will a JVM process see the updated time zone from the OS?

Tags: java, timezone

I would like to change the timezone on a **Linux** server where there is a running Java application, and the application should see the change without a restart.

Current default time zone on Linux is CEST, I will change it to UTC.

Unfortunately the current code relies on the default time zone, instead of specifying UTC explicitly.

(When) will Java see the change without restarting the app?

I made a quick test in **Windows 10** with Java 8 and changed the time zone manually to a timezone that has tomorrow's date already (2018-04-10) while my test was running and it did not update to my new time zone.

Here is the code:

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println( TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName() );
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
0 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
1 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
2 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
3 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
4 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
5 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
6 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
7 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
8 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
9 2018-04-09
Eastern European Time
```

Is this behavior defined? Does it depend on OS, and/or on Java version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the JVM starts, it loads the default timezone.

- it can be read from the OS: [Windows registry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/time-zone001.html#CBBIEBDG) or Linux `/etc/localtime` (or some other folder, depending on the distribution)
- it can be read from JVM params/properties: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2493805/7605325
- in runtime, an application can call `TimeZone.setDefault`

AFAIK, the third option is the only one that changes the default timezone **in runtime**. All the others require a JVM restart.

Answer (score 1):

The default timezone is cached by the JVM, but if you do this before checking the default timezone:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(null);
System.clearProperty("user.timezone");
```

You can trigger the JVM to re-read the system timezone setting. I experimented with this, and it worked for me. I don't know how expensive it is, however, to keep accessing the host system's timezone instead of using the cached copy, so you might want to be careful with how often you check for timezone changes like this.

Comment: Perfect. That what I needed.
This solution to re-read time zone from the OS I've been searching for 2-3 days.
The final code that I've used:
  `System.out.println("Before clear: "+ System.getProperty("user.timezone"));`
  `TimeZone.setDefault(null);`
  `System.clearProperty("user.timezone");`
  `TimeZone.getDefault();`
  `System.out.println("After clear: "+ System.getProperty("user.timezone"));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it at runtime, you can use the [java.util.TimeZone.setDefault()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)). I.e:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()));

        System.out.println(LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println( TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName() );

        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/ACT"));
        System.out.println(LocalDate.now());
        System.out.println( TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName() );

    }
```

The output:

```
[Africa/Abidjan, Africa/Accra, Africa/Addis_Ababa, Africa/Algiers, Africa/Asmara, Africa/Asmera, Africa/Bamako, Africa/Bangui, Africa/Banjul, Africa/Bissau, Africa/Blantyre, Africa/Brazzaville, Africa/Bujumbura, Africa/Cairo, Africa/Casablanca, Africa/Ceuta, Africa/Conakry, Africa/Dakar, Africa/Dar_es_Salaam, Africa/Djibouti, Africa/Douala, Africa/El_Aaiun, Africa/Freetown, Africa/Gaborone, Africa/Harare, Africa/Johannesburg, Africa/Juba, Africa/Kampala, Africa/Khartoum, Africa/Kigali, Africa/Kinshasa, Africa/Lagos, Africa/Libreville, Africa/Lome, Africa/Luanda, Africa/Lubumbashi, Africa/Lusaka, Africa/Malabo, Africa/Maputo, Africa/Maseru, Africa/Mbabane, Africa/Mogadishu, Africa/Monrovia, Africa/Nairobi, Africa/Ndjamena, Africa/Niamey, Africa/Nouakchott, Africa/Ouagadougou, Africa/Porto-Novo, Africa/Sao_Tome, Africa/Timbuktu, Africa/Tripoli, Africa/Tunis, Africa/Windhoek, America/Adak, America/Anchorage, America/Anguilla, America/Antigua, America/Araguaina, America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires, America/Argentina/Catamarca, America/Argentina/ComodRivadavia, America/Argentina/Cordoba, America/Argentina/Jujuy, America/Argentina/La_Rioja, America/Argentina/Mendoza, America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos, America/Argentina/Salta, America/Argentina/San_Juan, America/Argentina/San_Luis, America/Argentina/Tucuman, America/Argentina/Ushuaia, America/Aruba, America/Asuncion, America/Atikokan, America/Atka, America/Bahia, America/Bahia_Banderas, America/Barbados, America/Belem, America/Belize, America/Blanc-Sablon, America/Boa_Vista, America/Bogota, America/Boise, America/Buenos_Aires, America/Cambridge_Bay, America/Campo_Grande, America/Cancun, America/Caracas, America/Catamarca, America/Cayenne, America/Cayman, America/Chicago, America/Chihuahua, America/Coral_Harbour, America/Cordoba, America/Costa_Rica, America/Creston, America/Cuiaba, America/Curacao, America/Danmarkshavn, America/Dawson, America/Dawson_Creek, America/Denver, America/Detroit, America/Dominica, America/Edmonton, America/Eirunepe, America/El_Salvador, America/Ensenada, America/Fort_Nelson, America/Fort_Wayne, America/Fortaleza, America/Glace_Bay, America/Godthab, America/Goose_Bay, America/Grand_Turk, America/Grenada, America/Guadeloupe, America/Guatemala, America/Guayaquil, America/Guyana, America/Halifax, America/Havana, America/Hermosillo, America/Indiana/Indianapolis, America/Indiana/Knox, America/Indiana/Marengo, America/Indiana/Petersburg, America/Indiana/Tell_City, America/Indiana/Vevay, America/Indiana/Vincennes, America/Indiana/Winamac, America/Indianapolis, America/Inuvik, America/Iqaluit, America/Jamaica, America/Jujuy, America/Juneau, America/Kentucky/Louisville, America/Kentucky/Monticello, America/Knox_IN, America/Kralendijk, America/La_Paz, America/Lima, America/Los_Angeles, America/Louisville, America/Lower_Princes, America/Maceio, America/Managua, America/Manaus, America/Marigot, America/Martinique, America/Matamoros, America/Mazatlan, America/Mendoza, America/Menominee, America/Merida, America/Metlakatla, America/Mexico_City, America/Miquelon, America/Moncton, America/Monterrey, America/Montevideo, America/Montreal, America/Montserrat, America/Nassau, America/New_York, America/Nipigon, America/Nome, America/Noronha, America/North_Dakota/Beulah, America/North_Dakota/Center, America/North_Dakota/New_Salem, America/Ojinaga, America/Panama, America/Pangnirtung, America/Paramaribo, America/Phoenix, America/Port-au-Prince, America/Port_of_Spain, America/Porto_Acre, America/Porto_Velho, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Punta_Arenas, America/Rainy_River, America/Rankin_Inlet, America/Recife, America/Regina, America/Resolute, America/Rio_Branco, America/Rosario, America/Santa_Isabel, America/Santarem, America/Santiago, America/Santo_Domingo, America/Sao_Paulo, America/Scoresbysund, America/Shiprock, America/Sitka, America/St_Barthelemy, America/St_Johns, America/St_Kitts, America/St_Lucia, America/St_Thomas, America/St_Vincent, America/Swift_Current, America/Tegucigalpa, America/Thule, America/Thunder_Bay, America/Tijuana, America/Toronto, America/Tortola, America/Vancouver, America/Virgin, America/Whitehorse, America/Winnipeg, America/Yakutat, America/Yellowknife, Antarctica/Casey, Antarctica/Davis, Antarctica/DumontDUrville, Antarctica/Macquarie, Antarctica/Mawson, Antarctica/McMurdo, Antarctica/Palmer, Antarctica/Rothera, Antarctica/South_Pole, Antarctica/Syowa, Antarctica/Troll, Antarctica/Vostok, Arctic/Longyearbyen, Asia/Aden, Asia/Almaty, Asia/Amman, Asia/Anadyr, Asia/Aqtau, Asia/Aqtobe, Asia/Ashgabat, Asia/Ashkhabad, Asia/Atyrau, Asia/Baghdad, Asia/Bahrain, Asia/Baku, Asia/Bangkok, Asia/Barnaul, Asia/Beirut, Asia/Bishkek, Asia/Brunei, Asia/Calcutta, Asia/Chita, Asia/Choibalsan, Asia/Chongqing, Asia/Chungking, Asia/Colombo, Asia/Dacca, Asia/Damascus, Asia/Dhaka, Asia/Dili, Asia/Dubai, Asia/Dushanbe, Asia/Famagusta, Asia/Gaza, Asia/Harbin, Asia/Hebron, Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh, Asia/Hong_Kong, Asia/Hovd, Asia/Irkutsk, Asia/Istanbul, Asia/Jakarta, Asia/Jayapura, Asia/Jerusalem, Asia/Kabul, Asia/Kamchatka, Asia/Karachi, Asia/Kashgar, Asia/Kathmandu, Asia/Katmandu, Asia/Khandyga, Asia/Kolkata, Asia/Krasnoyarsk, Asia/Kuala_Lumpur, Asia/Kuching, Asia/Kuwait, Asia/Macao, Asia/Macau, Asia/Magadan, Asia/Makassar, Asia/Manila, Asia/Muscat, Asia/Nicosia, Asia/Novokuznetsk, Asia/Novosibirsk, Asia/Omsk, Asia/Oral, Asia/Phnom_Penh, Asia/Pontianak, Asia/Pyongyang, Asia/Qatar, Asia/Qyzylorda, Asia/Rangoon, Asia/Riyadh, Asia/Saigon, Asia/Sakhalin, Asia/Samarkand, Asia/Seoul, Asia/Shanghai, Asia/Singapore, Asia/Srednekolymsk, Asia/Taipei, Asia/Tashkent, Asia/Tbilisi, Asia/Tehran, Asia/Tel_Aviv, Asia/Thimbu, Asia/Thimphu, Asia/Tokyo, Asia/Tomsk, Asia/Ujung_Pandang, Asia/Ulaanbaatar, Asia/Ulan_Bator, Asia/Urumqi, Asia/Ust-Nera, Asia/Vientiane, Asia/Vladivostok, Asia/Yakutsk, Asia/Yangon, Asia/Yekaterinburg, Asia/Yerevan, Atlantic/Azores, Atlantic/Bermuda, Atlantic/Canary, Atlantic/Cape_Verde, Atlantic/Faeroe, Atlantic/Faroe, Atlantic/Jan_Mayen, Atlantic/Madeira, Atlantic/Reykjavik, Atlantic/South_Georgia, Atlantic/St_Helena, Atlantic/Stanley, Australia/ACT, Australia/Adelaide, Australia/Brisbane, Australia/Broken_Hill, Australia/Canberra, Australia/Currie, Australia/Darwin, Australia/Eucla, Australia/Hobart, Australia/LHI, Australia/Lindeman, Australia/Lord_Howe, Australia/Melbourne, Australia/NSW, Australia/North, Australia/Perth, Australia/Queensland, Australia/South, Australia/Sydney, Australia/Tasmania, Australia/Victoria, Australia/West, Australia/Yancowinna, Brazil/Acre, Brazil/DeNoronha, Brazil/East, Brazil/West, CET, CST6CDT, Canada/Atlantic, Canada/Central, Canada/East-Saskatchewan, Canada/Eastern, Canada/Mountain, Canada/Newfoundland, Canada/Pacific, Canada/Saskatchewan, Canada/Yukon, Chile/Continental, Chile/EasterIsland, Cuba, EET, EST5EDT, Egypt, Eire, Etc/GMT, Etc/GMT+0, Etc/GMT+1, Etc/GMT+10, Etc/GMT+11, Etc/GMT+12, Etc/GMT+2, Etc/GMT+3, Etc/GMT+4, Etc/GMT+5, Etc/GMT+6, Etc/GMT+7, Etc/GMT+8, Etc/GMT+9, Etc/GMT-0, Etc/GMT-1, Etc/GMT-10, Etc/GMT-11, Etc/GMT-12, Etc/GMT-13, Etc/GMT-14, Etc/GMT-2, Etc/GMT-3, Etc/GMT-4, Etc/GMT-5, Etc/GMT-6, Etc/GMT-7, Etc/GMT-8, Etc/GMT-9, Etc/GMT0, Etc/Greenwich, Etc/UCT, Etc/UTC, Etc/Universal, Etc/Zulu, Europe/Amsterdam, Europe/Andorra, Europe/Astrakhan, Europe/Athens, Europe/Belfast, Europe/Belgrade, Europe/Berlin, Europe/Bratislava, Europe/Brussels, Europe/Bucharest, Europe/Budapest, Europe/Busingen, Europe/Chisinau, Europe/Copenhagen, Europe/Dublin, Europe/Gibraltar, Europe/Guernsey, Europe/Helsinki, Europe/Isle_of_Man, Europe/Istanbul, Europe/Jersey, Europe/Kaliningrad, Europe/Kiev, Europe/Kirov, Europe/Lisbon, Europe/Ljubljana, Europe/London, Europe/Luxembourg, Europe/Madrid, Europe/Malta, Europe/Mariehamn, Europe/Minsk, Europe/Monaco, Europe/Moscow, Europe/Nicosia, Europe/Oslo, Europe/Paris, Europe/Podgorica, Europe/Prague, Europe/Riga, Europe/Rome, Europe/Samara, Europe/San_Marino, Europe/Sarajevo, Europe/Saratov, Europe/Simferopol, Europe/Skopje, Europe/Sofia, Europe/Stockholm, Europe/Tallinn, Europe/Tirane, Europe/Tiraspol, Europe/Ulyanovsk, Europe/Uzhgorod, Europe/Vaduz, Europe/Vatican, Europe/Vienna, Europe/Vilnius, Europe/Volgograd, Europe/Warsaw, Europe/Zagreb, Europe/Zaporozhye, Europe/Zurich, GB, GB-Eire, GMT, GMT0, Greenwich, Hongkong, Iceland, Indian/Antananarivo, Indian/Chagos, Indian/Christmas, Indian/Cocos, Indian/Comoro, Indian/Kerguelen, Indian/Mahe, Indian/Maldives, Indian/Mauritius, Indian/Mayotte, Indian/Reunion, Iran, Israel, Jamaica, Japan, Kwajalein, Libya, MET, MST7MDT, Mexico/BajaNorte, Mexico/BajaSur, Mexico/General, NZ, NZ-CHAT, Navajo, PRC, PST8PDT, Pacific/Apia, Pacific/Auckland, Pacific/Bougainville, Pacific/Chatham, Pacific/Chuuk, Pacific/Easter, Pacific/Efate, Pacific/Enderbury, Pacific/Fakaofo, Pacific/Fiji, Pacific/Funafuti, Pacific/Galapagos, Pacific/Gambier, Pacific/Guadalcanal, Pacific/Guam, Pacific/Honolulu, Pacific/Johnston, Pacific/Kiritimati, Pacific/Kosrae, Pacific/Kwajalein, Pacific/Majuro, Pacific/Marquesas, Pacific/Midway, Pacific/Nauru, Pacific/Niue, Pacific/Norfolk, Pacific/Noumea, Pacific/Pago_Pago, Pacific/Palau, Pacific/Pitcairn, Pacific/Pohnpei, Pacific/Ponape, Pacific/Port_Moresby, Pacific/Rarotonga, Pacific/Saipan, Pacific/Samoa, Pacific/Tahiti, Pacific/Tarawa, Pacific/Tongatapu, Pacific/Truk, Pacific/Wake, Pacific/Wallis, Pacific/Yap, Poland, Portugal, ROK, Singapore, SystemV/AST4, SystemV/AST4ADT, SystemV/CST6, SystemV/CST6CDT, SystemV/EST5, SystemV/EST5EDT, SystemV/HST10, SystemV/MST7, SystemV/MST7MDT, SystemV/PST8, SystemV/PST8PDT, SystemV/YST9, SystemV/YST9YDT, Turkey, UCT, US/Alaska, US/Aleutian, US/Arizona, US/Central, US/East-Indiana, US/Eastern, US/Hawaii, US/Indiana-Starke, US/Michigan, US/Mountain, US/Pacific, US/Pacific-New, US/Samoa, UTC, Universal, W-SU, WET, Zulu, EST, HST, MST, ACT, AET, AGT, ART, AST, BET, BST, CAT, CNT, CST, CTT, EAT, ECT, IET, IST, JST, MIT, NET, NST, PLT, PNT, PRT, PST, SST, VST]
2018-04-09
Greenwich Mean Time
2018-04-10
Australian Eastern Standard Time (New South Wales)
```