# Ignite logging timestamp different with OS system clocktime(ignite use wrong timezone?)

Tags: ignite

My ignite dumpped log have different timestamp(timezone?) with my OS system clocktime:

Ignite Log:

```
[04:02:51,119][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#10][TcpDiscoverySpi] Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.28.163:41705, rmtPort=41705]
[04:02:51,126][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#10][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.28.163:41705, rmtPort=41705
[04:02:51,172][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#8][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.28.162:42526, rmtPort=42526
[04:02:51,201][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#2][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.28.163, rmtPort=34146]
[04:02:51,201][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-#2][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.28.163, rmtPort=34146]
[04:02:51,202][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-#11][TcpDiscoverySpi] Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/192.168.28.163:34146, rmtPort=34146]
[04:02:51,208][INFO][disco-event-worker-#101][GridDiscoveryManager] Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=074891f6-2e53-415c-85f5-3f3896fe5c47, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.28.163], sockAddrs=[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.28.163:47500], discPort=47500, order=5, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1526371371120, loc=false, ver=2.4.0#20180305-sha1:aa342270, isClient=false]
[04:02:51,209][INFO][disco-event-worker-#101][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=5, servers=3, clients=0, CPUs=96, offheap=210.0GB, heap=30.0GB]
[04:02:51,209][INFO][disco-event-worker-#101][GridDiscoveryManager] Data Regions Configured:
[04:02:51,209][INFO][disco-event-worker-#101][GridDiscoveryManager]   ^-- default [initSize=10.0 GiB, maxSize=70.0 GiB, persistenceEnabled=true]
[04:03:28,673][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#71][IgniteKernal] 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=f687a6b6, uptime=00:01:00.007]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=3, nodes=3, CPUs=96]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.33%, avg=0.11%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=0]
    ^-- Heap [used=80MB, free=99.22%, comm=10240MB]
    ^-- Non heap [used=49MB, free=-1%, comm=50MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=2, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=7, qSize=0]
```

But my OS clocktime is:

```
[root@test3 apache-ignite]# cd /var/log/apache-ignite/
[root@test3 apache-ignite]# ls -trl
-rw-r--r-- 1 ignite ignite       0 May 15 16:02 ignite-074891f6.0.log.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 ignite ignite    5336 May 15 16:05 apache-ignite-gc.log.0.current
-rw-r--r-- 1 ignite ignite   20282 May 15 16:14 ignite-074891f6.0.log
[root@test3 apache-ignite]# date
Tue May 15 16:15:02 CST 2018
```

How could change the ignite runing time to the local timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timezone can be specified as a JVM parameter. Take a look at the following question: [How to set a JVM TimeZone Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly)

You can also change timezone of logged timestamp in logger configuration. For example, if you use the following timestamp format for Log4J, it will be printed in GMT+0 timezone:

```
%d{ISO8601}{GMT+0}
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue sovled, now the time is Ok