# play framework logs are in UTC even system timezone is IST

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, playframework, timezone, sbt

i set aws system timezone to IST.

```
$ timedatectl
  Local time: Fri 2018-06-15 16:43:20 IST
  Universal time: Fri 2018-06-15 11:13:20 UTC
  RTC time: Fri 2018-06-15 11:13:20
  Time zone: Asia/Kolkata (IST, +0530)
  Network time on: yes
  NTP synchronized: no
  RTC in local TZ: no
```

but play framework logs are still generating with UTC time zone

```
2018-06-15 11:22:46,002 [INFO] from application in main - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
```

i am using play framework 2.5
and i am running play framework by `sudo sbt clean dist`

Comment: Perhaps UTC is set on [logback PatternLayout](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) configuration, from the docs, the pattern can be set to `date{pattern, timezone}` thus forcing log records to be in a different timezone than the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [passing the timezone to the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly#answer-2493805) like so:

```
sbt -Duser.timezone=Asia/Kolkata
```

In `conf/logback.xml` there should be a conversion word [`%date`](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#date) in an element similar to

```
<pattern>%date [%level] from %logger in %thread - %message%n%xException</pattern>
```

Date conversion word has format `date{pattern, timezone}` and by default:

> ...in the absence of the timezone parameter, the default timezone of the
>   host Java platform is used.

Therefore the JVM, and not the OS, has the final word on the timezone.