# Ho do I set system timezone to UTC so that joda DateTime doesn't ignores it?

Tags: macos, scala, datetime, playframework, timezone

I'm using Scala along with play framework. So I've set my system timezone to UTC:

```
sudo systemsetup -gettimezone
Time Zone: GMT
```

But

```
println(DateTime.now().toString)
```

results into **"2018-10-10T19:29:40.886+02:00"** and all of the dates I operate in my code keep my actual timezone unless I set it manually by *withZone*. How do I set my system date properly? Would appreciate any help!

P.S. I'm using Postman for testing, so if there is a way to set it there it could also work...

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to set it manually by `withZone` (or whatever handles are in Joda-Time, it’s not my home field)? The JVM’s time zone setting can be changed at any time by other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM, so I wouldn’t be too comfortable relying on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a JVM TimeZone Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the JVM parameter: `"-Duser.timezone=GMT"` when starting your app.

If you start your app with `sbt run`, try:

```
env JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=GMT" sbt run
```

then the output for `println(DateTime.now().toString)`

is: `2018-10-10T18:20:45.386Z`