# LocalDate changing dateb when being saved to a mySQL database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

when i save a LocalDate field with the current date using spring boot to a mySQL Date column that way

```
LocalDate.now()
```

it saved with day-1 for example today is 10-08-2020 but in the database i found 09-08-2020
However, when i display the current date it return the correct date

Comment: check the timezone of the server

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pfedatabase?serverTimezone=UTC
But how to change it in the application.properties in order to return the correct current day

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37185444/5193536