# LocalDateTime.now() doesnt give the system local time

Tags: java, linux, time

I have a problem with `LocalDateTime.now()` returning the wrong time(off by 2 hours, the same as the timezone)

When I check the linux server the `date` command returns the right time, running `hwclock -r` shows the right time too.

This is from the command `timedatectl`
https://gyazo.com/9c70f5719a03492e0d7fdff3128f2f1d

The local time is what is shown in `date` and `hwclock -r` but `LocalDateTime.now()` returns the universal time/RTC time

Even MySQL shows the local time (doing `SELECT NOW()`)

Any ideas to why/what I have to change to make `LocalDateTime.now()` return the correct time - I know I could use a `ZonedTimeZone` but this is not only for my own projects but it also applies to other java programs/plugins running on the machine that I don't have control over

Comment: If you know what you’re doing, you can always use `LocalDateTime.now(yourDesiredTimeZoneId)`. For example `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Copenhagen"))`.

Comment: Yea I know I could also do that, but thx though! The problem still persist for the programs/plugins that isnt my own that use LocalDateTime.now()

Comment: Maybe the JVM default time zone has been set to UTC. That happens. To check, try `System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault());`.

Comment: The problem is that a plugin — the same one or a different one — may set the JVM default time zone. If that’s the issue, I can’t tell you the solution. Other than, as I said already, not rely on it. Which is always a good and sound idea.

Comment: @OleV.V. it also happens if I just build a standalone jar only containing a print of LocalDateTime.now() (like this https://gyazo.com/4d76e2614be8b17f8a08e77c610569ee) so I don't suspect its another plugin or am i wrong?

Comment: The ZoneId.systemDefault() do return Etc/UTC

Comment: Bingo! You may start `java` with `-Duser.timezone=Europe/Copenhagen`. It works until some plugin sets it otherwise … :-( Does this answer your question? [How to set a JVM TimeZone Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493749/how-to-set-a-jvm-timezone-properly)

Comment: @OleV.V. But if this runs by itself, and not as a plugin then nothing should be able to set it right?. I tried to run the jar with your argument but it didnt change the time, it still returns the universal time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247297/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-sumsar1812).

Answer (score 2):

With the help from @OleV.V I got it working with the jvm argument -Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris

For example:

```
java -Duser.timezone=Europe/Paris -jar TestProject.jar
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great working solution on a global level, it is been very useful in my case since i am working on so many different microservices

Answer (score 2):

## Wrong class

I cannot imagine a situation where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do.

The `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC.

When you call the `LocalDateTime.now` method, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. But keep in mind that the current default can be changed at runtime, at any moment, by any code in any app within that JVM.

Simply put, you are using the wrong class.

## `ZonedDateTime`

To capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, use `ZonedDateTime` class.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Comment: The OP explained to me in a chat that they used a 3rd party plugin in which the dubious/erroneous `LocalDateTIme.now()` call happened. I upvoted your answer as a guide to other readers. Hopefully not many are in the same situation as the OP.